# Split long string at the spaces

Tags: c#, .net, string

In my program, I need to split a string into multiple lines if it's too long. Right now I'm using this method:

```
private List<string> SliceString(string stringtocut)
{
    List<string> parts = new List<string>();
    int i = 0;
    do
    {  
        parts.Add(stringtocut.Substring(i, System.Math.Min(18, stringtocut.Substring(i).Length)));
        i += 18;
    } while (i < stringtocut.Length);
    return parts;
}
```

The only thing is that if the 19'th character isn't a space, we cut a word in half, and it looks really bad.

E.g.

String: 
This is a long sentance with more than 18 letters.

```
Sliced string: 
This is a long sent
ance with more than
 18 letters.
```

How would I cut the string so it's no longer than 18 characters per section, but go back to the nearest space if we can? I've been toying with the above algorithm for a bit, but I can't seem to get it.

Thanks!

Comment: You should look at `string.LastIndexOf(char, int, int)` method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe use a regular expression like this:

```
var input = "This is a long sentence with more than 18 letters.";
var output = Regex.Split(input, @"(.{1,18})(?:\s|$)")
                  .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
                  .ToList();
```

Returns the result:

```
[ "This is a long", "sentence with more", "than 18 letters." ]
```

---

**Update**

Here's a similar solution to handle really long words (although I have a feeling it won't perform quite as well, so you may want to benchmark this):

```
var input = "This is a long sentence with a reallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreally long word in it.";
var output = Regex.Split(input, @"(.{1,18})(?:\s|$)|(.{18})")
                  .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
                  .ToList();
```

This produces the result:

```
[ "This is a long", 
  "sentence with a", 
  "reallyreallyreally", 
  "reallyreallyreally", 
  "reallyreallyreally", 
  "reallyreallyreally", 
  "really long word", 
  "in it." ]
```

Comment: That's really cool. I wonder how would it perform against my solution considering really long strings.

Comment: However this cuts to chunks of 18 always, not only when it's possible to do so on word boundaries. I 'm not sure what the OP wants to happen in that case, but my interpretation of the question is that this should not happen.

Comment: @Jon It assumes there will be a whitespace character somewhere inside that 18-character chunk to break on. If there is not one, it will not behave quite as nicely.

Comment: Ah, that'll be a problem. I should have mentioned we need to split on a non space if we can't find a space to use

Comment: @Nathan: In that case it will *not* be a problem :-)

Comment: @Jon / Nathan It will break long words at most once. If there are > 36 characters in the word, the first substring will be longer than 18 characters. I'll work a solution to handle this case.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I don't image there will ever be an entry > 36 characters, but it's definitely a possibility, and failsafes are always nice. Would it be possible to explain or atleast overview how this thing works? It just looks so complicated and crazy :p

Comment: @p.s.w.g: I got it. Splits on space, up to 18 but goes over if no space found is `@"(?:(.{1,18})(?:\s|$)|(.+?)(?:\s|$))"`. Splits on space, up to 18 but forces split on 18 if no space found is `@"(?:(.{1,18})(?:\s|$)|(.{18}))"`. Thanks for showing this interesting approach.

Comment: pswgs answer works too I believe... I'll try them both out, I think they'll work fine. Thanks a bunch guys! regular expressions are really neat, I'd love to look into these more.

Answer (score 2):

This is really not optimized nor elegant code, but gives the desired result. It should be relatively easy to refactor :

```
string longSentence = "This is a long sentence with more than 18 letters.";

List<string> words = new List<string>();
string currentSentence = string.Empty;

var parts = longSentence.Split(' ');
foreach (var part in parts)
{
    if ((currentSentence + " " + part).Length < 18)
    {
        currentSentence += " " + part;
    }
    else
    {
        words.Add(currentSentence);
        currentSentence = part;
    }
}
words.Add(currentSentence);
words[0] = words[0].TrimStart();
```

Result :

```
This is a long
sentence with
more than 18
letters.
```

Basically you add each words up until you're about to bust 18 letters. At this point, you save the part and start over again. When it's over, you add up what's left. Also, there's an unnecessary space at the start that needs some trimming.

Comment: Thanks! This works ALMOST perfectly. Right now if I do a word that's more than 18 characters with no spaces, it inserts a blank entry into the array, and then the whole word. Would it be possible to just slice the word at 18 letters if its too long?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
int len = 0;
int index = 0;
text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                   text.SplitBy(' ')
                       .GroupBy(w =>
                                { 
                                    if (len + w.Length > 18)
                                    {
                                        len = 0;
                                        index++;
                                    }
                                    len += w.Length + 1;
                                    return index;
                                })
                       .Select(line => string.Join(" ", line)));
```

Comment: Not too sure how to use this, what is text?

Comment: @Nathan `text` is input `string`